# Design Consultation : Calling methods from multiple classes

Tags: java, oop

I am solving a problem where I will get an input from user in the following form.

```
{
"serviceA":true,
"serviceB":true,
"serviceC":false,
"serviceD":true,
"serviceE":false,
"score":10
}
```

Based on the user selection, I need to call services for score collection.This service call will update the score then by some margin. 
I have made packages for all these services.

One constraint here is, they are sequential i.e. B can be called only after A if both are enabled else B can be called directly.

I am using one Builder file where I will get the initial score as mentioned above with all service flags.Then I need to call all service method with this score. If I passed this score to serviceA then service B would need to know service A score also.

Comment: `I need to call services for score collection` -> What is the service method? What's its input / output

Comment: suggest you take a look at the chain of responsibility design pattern https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/chain_of_responsibility_pattern.htm

Answer (score 0):

using the chain of responsibility design pattern, I'd do something like that

```
interface ServiceInterface {

    public int getScore(int score);
}

class service implements ServiceInterface {

    private boolean enabled;
    private int factor;
    private ServiceInterface nextService = null;

    public serviceA(boolean enabled, int factor){
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.factor = factor;
    }

    public void setNextService(ServiceInterface service){
        this.nextService = service;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScore(int score) {
        if (this.enabled)
            score = score * this.factor;

        if (nextService != null)
            score = nextService.getScore(score);

        return score;
    }
}
```

and a simple run example would be

```
int score = 10;
service a = new service(false, 4);
service b = new service(true, 3);
a.setNextService(b);
System.out.println(a.getScore(score));
```

output

```
30
```

this will define `a -> b` as chain and call `getScore` of a and than `getScore` of b, this will calculate the score or skip based on the `enable` variable

you can also use inheritance and move more methods to the interface